# How can I create a map file with line numbers in Visual C++ 2005?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2005

I can find information to do what I want in VC++ 6.0 at [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/mapfile.aspx), but the options it suggests (e.g. /mapinfo:lines) are not supported in VC++ 2005.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question.

Comment: I know how to produce a map file in VS 2005. In VC++ 6.0, you could get lines numbers in the map file, by following the procedure in the codeproject link in the question. How can I get line numbers in the map file in VS 2005?

Comment: The PDB files include line number information.  If you want that, I suggest looking into using the [Debug Help library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for parsing and using .pdb files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer seems to be simple - you can't in any Visual C++ release after 2003.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bha0yc3d(v=VS.71).aspx shows support for the option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bha0yc3d(v=VS.80).aspx does not.

I had a bit of a search though and found http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/Locate_exception_position.aspx which describes how you can do equivalent debugging using COD files if you're somewhat familiar with assembler.