# Locate errors in shipped builds with C++ and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, logging

We ship builds of our software to customers, who run the code on data they cannot share due to data privacy. Therefore, we cannot normally debug on the data that causes errors (manifested as timeouts, exceptions, and crashes). Instead, when errors occur, I get an exception address which I then need to map to a code location. We currently use MSVC to compile the C++ code parts, but MSVC no longer allows to create a mapfile where I can find the source code line that produced the error ([How can I create a map file with line numbers in Visual C++ 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264862/how-can-i-create-a-map-file-with-line-numbers-in-visual-c-2005)). Is there any C++ compiler (for Windows, x86 and x64) that can be configured to produce a map file with accurate line numbers?

Also, I was looking at Boost.stacktrace for a solution, but another scenario we have is that a thread has to be stopped due a timeout from another thread. I am not sure I can get stack traces in Boost for other threads ...

The third thing I tried was to keep two variables lastFile, lastLineNo that are set using the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` defines. Spread around the code are numerous calls to

```
#define SET_OP lastFile = __FILE__; lastLineNo = __LINE__;
```

The problem with this approach is lastFile, lastLineNo are introduced in DLLs, but they should of course be thread-local (and delay-loaded DLLs do not play nicely with thread-local storage). Boost.Thread has thread-local storage, but I cannot find a way to obtain those variables from another thread in case of a timeout. Many of the calls to SET_OP are in functions where high performance is needed, so I'm a bit shy of complicated things that require mutexes.

I am getting a feeling I am pushing the bounds of what's possible with stacktraces in a multithreading scenario, but this is a very real problem that has given me headaches for weeks now, if not months.

Comment: Those map files with line numbers have been superseded with Program Database (.pdb) format long ago. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files?view=vs-2019

Comment: You asked for it, you get it: G++ and its binutils use "addr2line" for this, and the linker can produce map files. Perhaps it's time to abandon a stone-age old compiler and switch to something decent? Clang might also be a good choice. (Anyway, recommendations are off-topic on SO.)

Comment: @AlexF post-mortem dumps might contain sensitive data though.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I recently switched to supporting cmake, so I'll give g++ and addr2line a try. I'll have to ask my boss if we can generate dumps using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump for use with MSVC.

Comment: You could make `lastFile` a `std::atomic<char const*>` , but the fundamental problem remains that `lastFile` really is thread-local by nature. It would need to be a `[[threadlocal]] const char*`. If you register its address when the thread starts (so a `const char**`) you can still access that thread-local from another thread.

Comment: @IanAbbott: `WriteMiniDumpFile` can take a callback, which looks like a filter. It might be viable to dump everything except the sensitive data, if the callback can detect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I preferred an approach that could generate a full stack trace over approaches that translate a single address to a source code location. I was not able to solve the problem that boost.stacktrace does not produce a stack trace for endless loops in other threads. While it is possible to throw exceptions with stack traces with boost.stacktrace, there are too many cases where stack traces are not available. Hopefully, std::backtrace will make stack traces available for all exceptions. Until then, I opt to follow the instrumented source code approach. It is not perfect either, as our code base is much too big to fully instrument, and the third-party libraries do not support this kind of instrumentation anyway. So I came up with this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "Windows.h"
#undef min
#undef max
#endif

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#define StackTraceSize 20
class StackTrace final {
public:
    const char* mLastFileName = 0;
    int mLastLineNo = 0;
    std::string uncleanExits;

    // Constructor
    StackTrace() = default;

    // Destructor
    ~StackTrace() = default;

    // Store information about a scope that was entered
    void enterScope(const char* fileName, int lineNo);

    void update(int lineNo);

    // Forget information about a scope
    void leaveScope();

    // Generate string representation of the whole stack trace
    std::string toString() const;

    // Generate string representation of current stack frame
    std::string getCurrentStackFrameString() const;

private:
    int mCurrNo = -1;
    const char* mFileNames[StackTraceSize];
    int mLineNos[StackTraceSize];
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

std::mutex threadsWithStackTraceMutex;
std::map<std::thread::id, StackTrace*> threadsWithStackTraces;

StackTrace* getStackTrace(std::thread::id threadId)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(threadsWithStackTraceMutex);
    if (threadsWithStackTraces.count(threadId) == 0) {
        // threadsWithStackTraces[threadId] could fail theoretically, due to out of memory.
        // In that case, the new StackTrace would be leaked, but it probably wouldn't happen often,
        // due to the memory shortage ...
        threadsWithStackTraces[threadId] = new StackTrace();
    }
    // if addThread fails, there would be an exception. Otherwise, the assignment below should be safe.
    StackTrace* result = threadsWithStackTraces[threadId];
    return result;
}

void forgetStackTrace(std::thread::id threadId)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(threadsWithStackTraceMutex);
    if (threadsWithStackTraces.count(threadId) > 0) {
        delete threadsWithStackTraces[threadId];
        threadsWithStackTraces.erase(threadId);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// A simple integer storing the currently active operation - used for debugging
// crashes

// Store information about a scope that was entered
void StackTrace::enterScope(const char* fileName, int lineNo)
{
    if (mCurrNo < 0) {
        mCurrNo = 0;
    } else {
        ++mCurrNo;
    }

    if (mCurrNo < StackTraceSize) {
        mFileNames[mCurrNo] = fileName;
        mLineNos[mCurrNo] = lineNo;
    } else {
        mLastFileName = fileName;
        mLastLineNo = lineNo;
    }
}

// Update line number. Filename doesn't change here ... same scope (normally)
void StackTrace::update(int lineNo)
{
    if (mCurrNo >= 0 && mCurrNo < StackTraceSize) {
        mLineNos[mCurrNo] = lineNo;
    } else {
        mLastLineNo = lineNo;
    }
}

// Forget information about a scope
void StackTrace::leaveScope()
{
    --mCurrNo;

    if (mCurrNo == 0) {
        forgetStackTrace(std::this_thread::get_id());
    }
}

StackTrace* getStackTrace()
{
    StackTrace* result = getStackTrace(std::this_thread::get_id());
    return result;
}

// Generate string representation of current stack frame
std::string StackTrace::getCurrentStackFrameString() const
{
    //SET_SCOPE; // doesn't belong here!!! We don't want this function to appear in stack traces ...
    if (mCurrNo < StackTraceSize) {
        return std::string(mFileNames[mCurrNo]) + std::string(":") + std::to_string(mLineNos[mCurrNo]);
    } else {
        return std::string(mLastFileName) + std::string(":") + std::to_string(mLastLineNo);
    }
}

// Generate string representation of the stack trace
std::string StackTrace::toString() const
{
    //SET_SCOPE; // doesn't belong here!!! We don't want this function to appear in stack traces ...
    std::string result;
    int printNow = std::min(StackTraceSize, mCurrNo+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < printNow; ++i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            result += ", ";
        }
        result += mFileNames[i];
        result += ":";
        result += std::to_string(mLineNos[i]);
    }

    if (mCurrNo > StackTraceSize) {
        result += std::string(", (") + std::to_string(mCurrNo - StackTraceSize) +
            std::string(" unrecorded entries)");
    }
    if (mCurrNo >= StackTraceSize) {
        result += ", ";
        result += mLastFileName;
        result += ":";
        result += std::to_string(mLastLineNo);
    }

    return result;
}

std::string getStackTraceString(std::thread::id thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id())
{
    return getStackTrace(thread_id)->toString();
}

// Simple construct to print a message about missing RETURN statements
class StackInfo final {
public:
    bool cleanExit = false;
    StackTrace* mSt;

    StackInfo(StackTrace* st)
    : mSt(st)
    {
    }

    ~StackInfo()
    {
        if (!cleanExit) {
            if (mSt != nullptr) {
                if (!mSt->uncleanExits.empty()) {
                    mSt->uncleanExits += ",";
                }
                mSt->uncleanExits += mSt->getCurrentStackFrameString();
            }
        }
    }
};

#define SET_SCOPE StackTrace* st = getStackTrace(); st->enterScope(__FILE__, __LINE__); StackInfo stackInfo(st);
#define SET_OP st->update(__LINE__);
#define RETURN stackInfo.cleanExit = true; st->leaveScope(); return 

// For functions that are called very often, it is faster to pass the stack infos as a separate argument ...
#define SET_SCOPE_FAST StackInfo stackInfo(st); st->enterScope(__FILE__, __LINE__);

void logStackTrace()
{
    auto* st = getStackTrace();
    if (st != nullptr) {
        std::string msg = st->toString();
        std::cout << msg << std::endl;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Demo code

void func1(StackTrace* st, int recursions)
{
    SET_SCOPE_FAST;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i) {
        SET_OP;
        if (recursions > 0) {
            func1(st, recursions-1);
        }
    }
    RETURN;
}

void func2()
{
    SET_SCOPE;
    func1(st, 2);
    RETURN;
}

class ExceptionWithText: public std::exception {
public:
    std::string mMsg;

    ExceptionWithText(const std::string& msg)
        : mMsg(msg)
    {
    }

    const char* what() const noexcept override
    {
        return mMsg.c_str();
    }
};

void throw_Cpp_exception_with_backtrace()
{
    SET_SCOPE;
    std::string str = "Exception thrown - StackTrace: " + getStackTraceString();
    throw ExceptionWithText(str);
    RETURN;
}

void cause_Cpp_exception_with_no_backtrace()
{
    SET_SCOPE;
    std::vector<int> ints;
    std::cout << ints.at(2) + ints.at(3);
    RETURN;
}

void endless_loop()
{
    SET_SCOPE;
    while(1);
    RETURN;
}

void crash_divByZero()
{
    int i = 1;
    std::cout << i / (i-1);
}

int crash_deref_null()
{
    char* p = nullptr;
    return p[0];
}

int crash_infinite_recursion()
{
    return crash_infinite_recursion();
}

int crash_double_free()
{
    SET_SCOPE;
    char* p = new char[10];
    char* q = p;
    delete p;
    delete q;
    RETURN 0;
}

typedef void (*VoidFunc)();

class Functor {
public:
    bool mRunning = false;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime;
    std::thread* thread = nullptr;
    VoidFunc func = nullptr;
    std::string exceptionCaughtStr;

    Functor()
    : mRunning(false)
    {
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        SET_SCOPE;
        try {
            mRunning = true;
            SET_OP;
            func();
        } catch(std::exception e) {
            exceptionCaughtStr = e.what();
            StackTrace* st = getStackTrace();
            if (st != nullptr && !st->uncleanExits.empty()) {
                exceptionCaughtStr +=" - unclean exits: " + st->uncleanExits;
            }
        }
        mRunning = false;
        RETURN;
    }
};

std::string timeDiffStr(const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& t1)
{
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto duration = t2-t1;
    auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration);
    return std::to_string(milliseconds.count() / 1000.0) + std::string(" s");
}

#ifdef _WIN32
// Function to convert Windows system exceptions into C++ exceptions
void se_trans_func(unsigned int code, EXCEPTION_POINTERS* pExp)
{
    std::string msg = std::string("SEH exception code ")
        + std::to_string(code);

    switch (code) {
        case 0xc0000005: 
            msg += " (access violation)";
            break;
        case 0xc0000094: 
            msg += " (division by zero)";
            break;
    }

    msg += std::string(". Stacktrace: ") + getStackTraceString();
    throw std::exception(msg.c_str());
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    SET_SCOPE;
    // Catch an exception that includes a backtrace
    try {
        throw_Cpp_exception_with_backtrace();
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        st->uncleanExits.clear();
    }

    // Store an exception from another thread in a functor's exception text buffer
    try {
        Functor functor;
        functor.mRunning = true;
        functor.func = &throw_Cpp_exception_with_backtrace;
        functor.thread = new std::thread(std::ref(functor));
        while (functor.mRunning);
        functor.thread->join();
        delete functor.thread;
        std::cout << "Functor exception: " << functor.exceptionCaughtStr << std::endl;
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    // Catch an exception that includes a backtrace
    try {
        cause_Cpp_exception_with_no_backtrace();
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        StackTrace* st = getStackTrace();
        if (st != nullptr && !st->uncleanExits.empty()) {
            std::cout << "Unclean exits: " + st->uncleanExits << std::endl;
            st->uncleanExits.clear();
        }
    } catch(...) {
        std::cout << "An unknown Exception was caught. " << std::endl;
    }

    // Store an exception from another thread in a functor's exception text buffer
    try {
        Functor functor;
        functor.mRunning = true;
        functor.func = &cause_Cpp_exception_with_no_backtrace;
        functor.thread = new std::thread(std::ref(functor));
        while (functor.mRunning);
        functor.thread->join();
        delete functor.thread;
        std::cout << "Functor exception: " << functor.exceptionCaughtStr << std::endl;
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    // See if we can get a stacktrace for another thread that hit an endless loop
    try {
        Functor functor;
        functor.mRunning = true;
        functor.func = &endless_loop;
        functor.thread = new std::thread(std::ref(functor));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        if (functor.mRunning) {
            std::cout << "Stack trace for other thread in endless loop: " 
                      << getStackTraceString(functor.thread->get_id())
                      << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Why did the endless loop end?" << std::endl;
        }
    } catch(std::exception e) {
        std::cout << "Exception caught: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    // Test Windows exceptions
    // todo: this exception is treated correctly, but a previous entry remained in the stack trace
    // (cause_Cpp_exception_with_no_backtrace)
    #ifdef _WIN32
    SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | SEM_NOALIGNMENTFAULTEXCEPT | SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);
    _set_se_translator(se_trans_func);

    try {
        crash_divByZero();
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    #endif

    try {
        // Test performance with a single thread
        {
            auto t1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            func2();
            std::cout << "Program phase 1 duration: " << timeDiffStr(t1) << std::endl;
        }

        // Now, test performance with several threads
        {
            size_t threads = 4;
            std::vector<Functor> functorVector;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < threads; ++i) {
                functorVector.emplace_back(Functor());
            }
            int endedThreads = 0;
            while (endedThreads < 8) {
                for (size_t i = 0; i < threads; ++i) {
                    Functor& functor = functorVector[i];
                    if (functor.thread == nullptr) {
                        functor.mRunning = true;
                        functor.func = &func2;
                        functor.thread = new std::thread(std::ref(functor));
                        functor.startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                    } else if (!functor.mRunning) {
                        functor.thread->join();
                        delete functor.thread;
                        functor.thread = nullptr;
                        std::cout << "Functor " << i << " duration: " << timeDiffStr(functor.startTime) << std::endl;
                        ++endedThreads;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(std::exception e) {
        std::cout << "Exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    RETURN 1;
}
```

This produces the output:

```
Exception caught: Exception thrown - StackTrace: C:\Temp\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:362, C:\Temp\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:249
Functor exception: Unknown exception - unclean exits: C:\Temp\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:249
Exception caught: invalid vector subscript
Unclean exits: C:\Temp\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:257
Functor exception: invalid vector subscript - unclean exits: C:\Temp\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:257
Stack trace for other thread in endless loop: C:\Temp\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:317, C:\Temp\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:265
SEH exception code 3221225620 (division by zero). Stacktrace: C:\Temp\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:362, C:\Temp\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:249, C:\Temp\stackTraceTest\main.cpp:257
Program phase 1 duration: 3.867000 s
Functor 1 duration: 5.182000 s
Functor 0 duration: 5.236000 s
Functor 2 duration: 5.291000 s
Functor 3 duration: 5.319000 s
Functor 1 duration: 5.128000 s
Functor 0 duration: 5.179000 s
Functor 2 duration: 5.138000 s
Functor 3 duration: 5.240000 s
```

Comments are still highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an answered question but just want to add

https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker

may help.